# How to view hidden files using Linux `find` command

Tags: linux, command-line-interface, grep, find, files

On a Linux server, I need to find all files with a certain file extension in the current directory and all sub-directories.

Previously, I have always used the following command:

```
find . -type f | grep -i *.php
```

However, it doesn't find hidden files, for example `.myhiddenphpfile.php`. The following finds the hidden `php` files, but not the non-hidden ones:

```
find . -type f | grep -i \.*.php
```

How can I find both the hidden and non-hidden `php` files in the same command?

Comment: You know that the "re" in "grep" stands for "regular expression", right? I have no clue how either of those command lines are supposed to work...

Answer (score 31, accepted):

...

```
find . -type f -name '*.php'
```

Comment: Any recursive option? This doesn't seem to be going into subdirectories where I ran the command. I don't know what directory the file is in.

Comment: What if I want both files and directories that may be hidden or not?

Comment: @Rodrigo, just leave out `-type f`, like so: `find . -name '*.php'`.

Comment: For anyone who wanna find all hidden files, you could try `find . -name ".[^.]*"`

Answer (score 10):

It's better to use iname (case insensitive).

I use this find command to search hidden files:

```
find /path -type f -iname ".*" -ls
```

Extracted from: http://www.sysadmit.com/2016/03/linux-ver-archivos-ocultos.html

Answer (score 1):

The issue is grep, not the find (try just `find . -type f` to see what I mean).

If you don't quote the `*` then the shell will expand it - before grep even sees its command line arguments; since the shell doesn't find hidden files by default, you'll have issues.

The reason it's *only* finding the hidden file is because the shell has already expanded the `*` and so grep is only matching that one file.