# How to use find to delete hidden files and folders

Tags: bash, terminal, find, search

How can I find and delete all files, including hidden ones, that do not not have the extension `java`. I know how to use find to delete files and run this command:

```
find . -not -name "*.java" -type f -delete
```

This recursively searches folders all for all files that do not end in *.java. But the command misses files in folders that are hidden.

I run the command found [here](http://osxdaily.com/2013/01/29/list-all-files-subdirectory-contents-recursively/): `ls -lahR` And I found that the command I ran missed files. For example:

```
./node_modules/.bin:
total 24
drwxr-xr-x  5 whitecat  staff   170B Apr  5 12:47 .
drwxr-xr-x  4 whitecat  staff   136B Apr  5 02:25 ..
lrwxr-xr-x  1 whitecat  staff    19B Apr  5 12:47 nopt -> ../nopt/bin/nopt.js
lrwxr-xr-x  1 whitecat  staff    20B Apr  5 12:47 semver -> ../semver/bin/semver
lrwxr-xr-x  1 whitecat  staff    19B Apr  5 12:47 shjs -> ../shelljs/bin/shjs
```

What flags do I need to not miss these "hidden" files. I've seen "[How to view hidden files using Linux `find` command](https://serverfault.com/questions/139126/how-to-view-hidden-files-using-linux-find-command)" and that only shows the command `find /path -type f -iname ".java" -ls`. I have already use that command and it still misses the hidden files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `-type f` you are looking for files.

The three files you mentioned are symbolic links:

> `rwxr-xr-x  1 whitecat  staff    19B Apr  5 12:47 nopt -> ../nopt/bin/nopt.js`

To find links you need to find for `-type l`

So to delete this symlinks you would have to change your command to (edited with the input of Whitecat's comment below):

```
find . -not -name "*.java" -type f -delete -o -type l -delete
```

Comment: I have to run a separate command for both `f` and `l`. I tried with both `-type  fl` and it didn't work.

Comment: you could use `-type f -o -type l` then you could find symlinks and files at the same time and you don't have to run two commands.

Comment: The final command would look like this: `find . -not -name "*.java" -type f -o -type l -delete`

Comment: @Whitecat You should probably group it like `\( -type f -o -type l \)`.  A future findutils release will support `-type f,l` as well.